# A weird behaviour of SFINAE

Tags: c++, sfinae

I met a weird behaviour when implementing a SFINAE class.
I want to use SFINAE to allow several types to be implemented. And disallow other types

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    using Enable = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, std::string>::value>;
    std::tuple<T> data; //(1)
};
class NotAllowedType{};
class A: public Base<std::string>{}; //(2)
class B: public Base<NotAllowedType>{};

int main()
{
    B b;
}
```

The thing is, it can pass compile.
If (1) or (2) commented, it fails the compile as expected

I uses g++ -std=c++17

Comment: It doesn't compile: https://wandbox.org/permlink/zQ5EeZHGFp0zoW5O. The question is not clear for me.

Comment: Just a side note, you can use the second argument of `std::enable_if` to pass T, so you don't really have to have an extra Enable type: `tuple<enable_if_t<is_same_v<T,string>,T>>`.

Comment: Try using gcc 7.3.0 c++17(GNU), It pass the compile. So it seems a bug of compiler, right?

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug that is already fixed in a later version. Update your compiler or switch to clang. It works as expected in all versions of clang that support C++17 and are available on wandbox.